# Mobius function on values of an irreducible quadratic polynomial

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers

Are there infinitely many integers $n$ for which $n^2 + 1$ is square-free, and has an even number of (necessarily distinct) prime factors ?

Comment: Yes. For instance, look at values of the form 10.m^2.

Comment: @Pasten sorry, I meant odd. Edited.

Comment: Fine. Then 2.m^2.

Comment: @Pasten you are right, thanks a lot. I edited accordingly.

Comment: It is certainly known that there are infinitely many $n$ such that $n^2 + 1$ is square-free (due to Estermann). It is also known (due to Iwaniec) that there are infinitely many $n$ such that $n^2 + 1$ is either prime or a product of two primes. Thus, either your conjecture is true or $n^2 + 1$ is prime infinitely often. In general I think sieves are not good at picking up the parity of number of prime factors, so it may not be straightforward to prove this